# How to serve django and gatsby on single vhost?

Tags: python, django, apache, gatsby, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy gatsby based frontend with django based backend under a single domain. It will rely on Apache and mod_wsgi. In a perfect world it should work as following:

- https://my-domain.com/ - gatsby frontend
- https://my-domain.com/admin - django
- https://my-domain.com/api - django

I can see two possibilities:

1. Django is aware of frontend. Serve everything via Django, setup `/` as a STATIC_URL.
2. Django is not aware of frontend. Serve `/api` and `/admin` via django. `/` is handled by a webserver.

I feel more comfortable with the second approach, however I do not know how to configure VirtualHost for such a scenario. The firstch approach looks like an ugly hack.

How should I proceed with that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you don't need it anymore, but it may be useful for others.

I ran into the same problem and the solution turned out to be using [assertPrefix](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/#additional-considerations) specifically in gatsby-config.js (for example, "/static/", it replaces the path only for static files and does not change the path for .html files) instead of pathPrefix (which replaces the path of each file)

```
module.exports = {
   assetPrefix: "/static/",
   ...
}
```

Now in django settings it remains only to specify the same `STATIC_URL = "/static/"` and the absolute path to the folder with files that gatsby gives after `gatsby build --prefix-paths`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"frontend/public/"),).
```

Also specify templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR/'frontend/public')],
    ...
    }
]
```

Next, you need to create a url path in django. For example:

```py
#main/urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include('backend.urls')),
    path(r'', include('frontend.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # this line is optional, but if you use MEDIA_ROOT, then it can be written this way
```

and

```py
#frontend/urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('', mainpage),
    path('app/',app),
    path('login/',login),
    path('user/<int:userid>',userid),
]
```

Views can look like this for example:

```py
#frontend/views*
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    
mainpage = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")
app = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="app/index.html")
user = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user/index.html")
login = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="login/index.html")
error = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404/index.html")
userid = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user/[userid]/index.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

After compiling your gatsby project, it should be served by django as a static page.

First: The gatsby dist should be in your `static_private` path.

Second: In your django project, you will define a URL for / that will call an index view let's say.

Finally: in your view you should render `index.html` of your gatsby dist.

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('apis/', include('apps.urls')),
    path('/', views.index),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Note that if you are handling routing in your frontend your url pattern for the index view should be like this : `re_path('^.*$', views.index)`

If you are hosting your django app on heroku you will need the whitenoise middleware and set it up in your `settings.py` :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

A doc is available here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise

Comment: Gatsby build is splitted across several different files. AFAIK index.html has to be inside templates directory and all other gatsby files inside STATIC_ROOT. And I have to set STATIC_URL to `/`, as in other case index.html won't find them. Am I right?

I'm not sure what do you mean by `static_private`.

Comment: in Django you need to put static files in `static_private` is defined in your `settings.py` then stored in `STATICFILES_DIRS` . 

Regarding your gatsby files, I'm talking about the production build files that are in `public` all those files needs to be in the django's static path. let me know if it's clear, I will update my answer

Comment: Could you provide an example settings.py file? I still cannot solve several different problems: re_path('^.*$', views.index) will catch everything, including gatsby static files, I cannot set a proper STATIC_URL = '/' as it will clash with MEDIA_URL, I do not know how to configure TEMPLATES and STATICFILES_DIRS (gatsby index.html should belong to both of them?).

Comment: were you able to find a solution ? we can have a chat if you want, it will be easier to explain maybe ?